# EntityFramework(C#)のToList()が極端に遅くなる原因を知りたい

Tags: c#, entity-framework

#### 解決したいこと

C# + Entity Frameworkアプリケーションで`Take()`をかまさない`ToList()`が極端に遅い原因を知りたい。

プログラム作成中にリスト表示箇所が極端に遅かったため、`VisualStudio`のデバッグ機能にて問題個所を調べたところ
`ToList()`で極端に遅くなっていることに気づきました。

#### 該当するソースコード

```
using (var db = new AppDbContext())
{
    Decimal pKey1 = XXX;
    Decimal pKey2 = XXXXX;
    Decimal pCode = XX;

    var r1 = db.V_DATA
        .Where(s => s.Key1 == pKey1)
        .Where(s => s.Key2 == pKey2)
        .Where(s => s.Code <= pCode)
        .ToList();  // ここで7,363ミリ秒(7秒程)かかる
}
============================
/// Entityクラス
public partial class V_DATA
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0, TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal Key1 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal Key2 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal Key3 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string Column4 { get; set; } // 最大

    [Key]
    [Column(Order =4 , TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal Column5 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 5, TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal Column6 { get; set; }
}
```

`ToList()`で取得される件数は`100件`。試しに`ToList()`直前に生成されたSQLを`SSMS`から実行しましたが
ほぼ0秒で結果が返ってきたためクエリチューニングの問題ではないように思えました。

```cs
var r1 = db.V_DATA
    .Where(s => s.Key1 == pKey1)
    .Where(s => s.Key2 == pKey2)
    .Where(s => s.Code <= pCode)
    .Selct(s => s); // デバッグモードで停止してSql文字列を取得
```

### 質問

以下の点についてご教示をお願い致します。

- `Take()`無しで速度を向上する方法を知りたい。
- `ToList()`のみで極端に遅くなる理由を知りたい。

なお、`V_DATA`は`SQLServer`データベースにおいて`View`として定義されています。

#### 検証したこと１（Take(100).ToList()）⇒少し早くなる(及第点)

```cs
var r1 = db.V_DATA
    .Where(s => s.Key1 == pKey1)
    .Where(s => s.Key2 == pKey2)
    .Where(s => s.Code <= pCode)
    .Take(100)  // ToList()で取得される件数と同数の100を指定
    .ToList();  // 早くなった。⇒1,112ミリ秒(1秒程)
```

#### 検証したこと２（ToArray）⇒遅い

```cs
var r1 = db.V_DATA
    .Where(s => s.Key1 == pKey1)
    .Where(s => s.Key2 == pKey2)
    .Where(s => s.Code <= pCode)
    .ToArray();  // ToArray化。同様に遅い。⇒7,576ミリ秒(7秒程)
```

#### 検証したこと３（Any）⇒早い

```cs
var r1 = db.V_DATA
    .Where(s => s.Key1 == pKey1)
    .Where(s => s.Key2 == pKey2)
    .Where(s => s.Code <= pCode)
    .Any();  // Any()化。早い。⇒49ミリ秒(7秒程)
```

#### 計測

別の質問サイトで指摘いただき計測しましたので、そちらのコードも載せます。

```cs
   var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    var r0 = db.V_DATA
        .Where(s => s.Key1 == pKey1)
        .Where(s => s.Key2 == pKey2)
        .Where(s => s.Code <= pCode);
    var endTime = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine ($"Where ×3 に要した時間 {endTime - startTime}");
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
    var r1 = r0.ToList (); 
    endTime = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine ($"ToList に要した時間 {endTime - startTime}");
```

1. 結果↓

```
Where ×3 に要した時間 00:00:00.0021529
ToList に要した時間 00:00:06.9929449
```

2. `Where().Take(100).ToList()とつなげた場合

```
Where ×1 に要した時間 00:00:00
Take(100) に要した時間 00:00:00.0032364
ToList に要した時間 00:00:00.8432526
```

`ToList`がはやくなります。。

#### その他

`V_DATA`ビューは概ね以下の定義になっています。
Column4の最大桁数は`11桁`、その他数値項目は`12桁`です。

```sql
[dbo].[V_DATA](
    [Key1] [numeric](6, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Key2] [numeric](7, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Key3] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Column4] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Column5] [numeric](22, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Column6] [numeric](22, 0) NOT NULL,
)
```

#### 利用バージョンなど

- Windows 10
- Windows Forms アプリケーション
- .NET Framework 4.8
- Entity Framework 6.2.0
- SQL Server 2014

困っています。ご回答お待ちしております。

### 追記 2020/10/29 16:00

## SQL直接実行で早くなった

`db.Database.Log = Console.Write;`にて生成されたSQLを取得し、`SqlQuery`で実行したところ、想定外に応答が早く(`170ミリ秒`)なりました。原因不明です。

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<List<V_DATA>>(/* ここに生成されたSQL文字列 */).ToList()
```

Comment: もしかしたらこの辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Entity framework .ToList() is slow? (Query all)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30250303/9014308), [EF LINQ ToList is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26733248/9014308) それから別の質問サイトはこちらですよね。[EntityFrameworkでToList()が極端に遅くなる](https://qiita.com/s_izumi/questions/f60bd3a14a8f85b030b1)

Comment: `Entity Framework.ToList() is slow?`を参考にビュー定義の方を疑ったところ、改善しました。実はビューで分析関数`LAG()`を利用しています。
試しにこのカラムをオンコードで`0`を返すように修正したところ、速度が改善しましたので、
これが読み込みを遅延させている原因かもしれません。

私としては`LAG()を使用しないビューに書き直すことで解決`となりそうですが
他の解決案があるかも併せて知りたいため、今日一日だけ未解決のまま回答を募集したいと思います。

とてもはやい回答を頂き krunif様ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決してるようなので余談ですが、Linqは遅延実行されるので、実際に要素を取り出すまでクエリが実行されていないはずです。つまり、Where ×3 に要した時間は実際のDBアクセスの時間ではないはずです。Any()も実際には何もしてない可能性が高いです

Comment: 直接実行のSQLはログとまったく同一ですか？パラメタで渡している部分をリテラルに変えると早くなることはありえます。また、単に２回目は早いということも考えられますが、順序入れ替えて複数実行しても同じですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[データベース操作のログ記録と受信](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception)でどのようなクエリが投げられているかを確認してみてください。

> なお、`V_DATA`はSQLServerデータベースにおいてViewとして定義されています。

Viewは単なるクエリです。参照の度にクエリが展開されテーブルから読み込み直します。

SQL Serverにはインデックス付きのビューという機能もありますが、Enterprise Editionでしか結果が使われません。（[クエリ オプティマイザーによる自動的なインデックス付きのビュー使用](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/sql/2014/getting-started/features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2014?view=sql-server-2014#rdbms-manageability)）

---

> SQL直接実行で早くなった

```
/// Entityクラス
public partial class V_DATA
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0, TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal Key1 { get; set; }
```

Entityクラスのすべてのメンバーに`[Key]`が付けられています。これは適切でしょうか？ 主キーでないものには付けるべきではありません。

---

また、[追跡なしのクエリ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ef/ef6/querying/no-tracking)として[`.AsNoTracking()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.asnotracking?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)を追加することができます。これを行うとオブジェクト状態が追跡されなくなるためオブジェクト生成が高速化されます。ただし、オブジェクトの値を更新後にDBへ保存できなくなります。

Comment: こんなに簡単にコンソール出力ができることは知りませんでした。
早速ログを確認しました。クエリはとても一般的なものになりましたが、`7306ミリ秒`かかりました。

```Log
 で接続を開きましたSELECT /* 文字数のため省略 */
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Key1] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Key2] = @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[Key3] <= cast(98 as decimal(18)))
-- p__linq__0: '201903' (Type = Decimal, IsNullable = false, Precision = 6)
-- p__linq__1: '160' (Type = Decimal, IsNullable = false, Precision = 3)
-- 2020/10/29 13:31:29 +09:00
 で実行しています-- 7306 ミリ秒で完了しました。結果: SqlDataReader
```

Comment: 悩ましいことに、新しい質問が生まれました。
ログに吐かれたクエリを`db.Database.SqlQuery<List<V_DATA>>(/* ここにSQL文字列 */).ToList()`で直接実行してみました。
すると`170ミリ秒`で結果が帰ってきたのです。

```Log
2020/10/29 13:40:23 +09:00
 で接続を閉じました2020/10/29 13:40:23 +09:00
 で接続を開きました SELECT /* 文字数のため省略 */
-- 2020/10/29 13:40:23 +09:00
 で実行しています-- 170 ミリ秒で完了しました。結果: SqlDataReader
```

内部での実行形式が全く違うのでしょうか？
改めてよろしくお願いします。

Comment: @s_izumi 質問文に加筆していただけますか？